# type string is not a subtype of type int in flutter

Tags: javascript, java, flutter, dart

I have this problem with this code, I tried to convert the variables into dynamic But it did not work, I hope someone knows the solution, thank you Please help.

I have this problem with this code, I tried to convert the variables into dynamic But it did not work, I hope someone knows the solution, thank you Please help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/weather.dart';

class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LocationScreen({this.locationWeather});
  final locationWeather;
  @override
  _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}

class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  WeatherModel weather = WeatherModel();
  int temperature;
  String weatherIcon;
  String cityName;
  String weatherMessage;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // ignore: todo
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    updateUI(widget.locationWeather);
  }

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  void updateUI(dynamic WeatherData) {
    setState(() {
      temperature = WeatherData['main']['temp'];

      var condition = WeatherData['weather'][0]['description'];

      weatherIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);

      weatherMessage = weather.getMessage(temperature);

      cityName = WeatherData['name'];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/location_background.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.near_me,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.location_city,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      '$temperature°',
                      style: kTempTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      weatherIcon,
                      style: kConditionTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                  '$weatherMessage as  in $cityName',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  style: kMessageTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript? One is essentially a toy, designed for writing small pieces of code, and traditionally used and abused by inexperienced programmers.

The other is a scripting language for web browsers.

Comment: Hey, mostly it is your model. You might returning integer for 'temp' key in WeatherData. But until you post your model too, can't confirm.

Comment: @Pushpendra Check this 
https://codeshare.io/24r69L

Comment: It seems that your WeatherData (json I'm assuming) is providing a string instead of an int for temperature and/or condition. Try passing int.parse(condition) and int.parse(temperature) to your WeatherModel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  void updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
    setState(() {
      if (weatherData == null) {
        temperature = 0;
        weatherIcon = 'Error';
        weatherMessage = 'Unable to get weather data';
        cityName = '';
        return;
      }
      double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
      temperature = temp.toInt();
      var condition = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
      weatherIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);
      weatherMessage = weather.getMessage(temperature);
      cityName = weatherData['name'];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing data from map, you need to explicitly tell that its an int , try casting `WeatherData['weather'][0]['description']` to `WeatherData['weather'][0]['description'] as int` . Also if any data is nullable, you need to tell that explicitly as well with a question mark `int?` , not sure if your model `WeatherData` allows that or not.

```
    setState(() {
      temperature = WeatherData['main']['temp']  as int ;

      var condition = WeatherData['weather'][0]['description'];

      weatherIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(condition);

      weatherMessage = weather.getMessage(temperature);

      cityName = WeatherData['name'];
    });
  }
```